# Ending a session on browser close only

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to end a user's session when they close the browser,
because they never logout properly.

I need to change a value in the db after they close the browser only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = check;
    function check() {
        return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
        //or put whatever function you need to call when a user closes the web //browser.
        endSession();
    }
</script>
```

This does work on closing the browser but unfornately also when I redirect to any other page.

Is there any way to do this for browser close only?

Grant.

Comment: Due to the stateless nature of http, close/redirect/reload all are considered the same in browser js realm.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question, I want you to know that there is no fool-proof technique to catch the browser close event for 100% of time. The trouble lies in the stateless nature of HTTP.

First create a page AutoLogOut.aspx and in Page_Load event write this code:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

Then add following javascript code in your page or Master Page:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var clicked = false;
    function CheckBrowser()
    {
        if (clicked == false)
        {
            //Browser closed
        }
        else
        {
            //redirected 
            clicked = false;
        }
    }

    function bodyUnload()
    {
        if (clicked == false)//browser is closed
        {
            var request = GetRequest();

            request.open("GET", "AutoLogOut.aspx", true);
            request.send();
        }
    }

    function GetRequest()
    {
        var request = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            //incase of IE7,FF, Opera and Safari browser
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            //for old browser like IE 6.x and IE 5.x
            request = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        }
        return request;
    }
```

Finally on your body tag add these event handlers:-

```
<body onunload="bodyUnload();" onclick ="clicked=true;>
```

Now when user closes the browser, it will close session on server. However I just like to highlight that this solution might not work 100% time as there are chances that when user close the browser, he is not connected to internet.
This link might help you. [Kill Session on Browser Close](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed)

Comment: As I said and also noted by others there is no full proof technique. It may work or may not.

Comment: an updated version of your answer is working thanks, but not on firefox which is where I need it to work. That link was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to call some ajax inside your "onbeforeunload" function. This ajax would then call a server page that would set your "value in the db".

However using "onbeforeunload" is frowned upon if it stops the user from closing the browser. It is considered bad practice.